# Cannot get Fiddler4 to capture requests when recording a web test through Visual Studio 2012 with IE10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, fiddler

Fiddler4 captures traffic if I use a browser without recording a web test but as soon as I launch a web test recorder browser no requests are being captured. Is it possible that the web test recorder intercepts these requests first?

I'm using:

Windows 8

Internet Explorer 10

Visual Studio 2012

Fiddler 4

Comment: In your "Web Test Recorder browser" click Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings. What are the proxy settings?

Comment: @EricLaw It's set to Automatically Detect Settings

Comment: Is your [request tree also set to use "default"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400220(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: 'Automatically Detect Settings' being set while Fiddler is running indicates that something (VS itself?) changed the proxy setting out from underneath Fiddler. Fiddler should be showing a yellow warning bar in that case. Is it?

Comment: @EricLaw It did, but it isn't anymore. I don't know why it disappeared